# Prevent creation of related object while creating one using factory boy. To prevent database access in PyTest

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

I have a two models

```py
import uuid

from django.db import models


class Currency(models.Model):
    """Currency model"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False,
                            blank=False, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False,
                              blank=False, default='$')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.code


class Transaction(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(
        Currency, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    payment_intent_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=True, blank=False, default=None)
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name} - {self.id} : {self.currency}"

    @property
    def link(self):
        """
            Link to a payment form for the transaction
        """
        return f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/{str(self.id)}'
```

And three serializers

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.validators import (MaxLengthValidator,
                                    ProhibitNullCharactersValidator)
from rest_framework import serializers

from apps.Payment.models import Currency, Transaction


class CurrencySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Currency
        fields = ['name', 'code', 'symbol']
        if settings.DEBUG == True:
            extra_kwargs = {
                'name': {
                    'validators': [MaxLengthValidator, ProhibitNullCharactersValidator]
                },
                'code': {
                    'validators': [MaxLengthValidator, ProhibitNullCharactersValidator]
                }
            }


class UnfilledTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    currency = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='code',
        queryset=Currency.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = (
            'name',
            'currency',
            'email',
            'message'
        )


class FilledTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    currency = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    link = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            """Non editable fields"""
            'id': {'read_only': True},
            'creation_date': {'read_only': True},
            'payment_intent_id': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

And two views

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from apps.Payment.models import Currency, Transaction
from apps.Payment.serializers import (CurrencySerializer,
                                      FilledTransactionSerializer,
                                      UnfilledTransactionSerializer)


class CurrencyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Currency.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CurrencySerializer


class TransactionViewset(ModelViewSet):
    """Transaction Viewset"""

    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return UnfilledTransactionSerializer
        else:
            return FilledTransactionSerializer
```

Also a signal

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from apps.Payment.models import Transaction
from apps.Payment.utils import fill_transaction


@receiver(post_save, sender=Transaction)
def transaction_filler(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' fill 'payment_intent_id' field in a transacton before saving '''

    if created:
        fill_transaction(instance)
```

In below code both test case passes (as I used database while testing)

```py
class TestUnfilledTransactionSerializer:
    def test_serialize_model(self):
        transaction = TransactionFactory.build()
        expected_serialized_data = {
            'name': transaction.name,
            'currency': transaction.currency.code,
            'email': transaction.email,
            'message': transaction.message,
        }

        serializer = UnfilledTransactionSerializer(transaction)
        assert serializer.data == expected_serialized_data

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_serialized_data(self):
        c = CurrencyFactory()
        transaction = TransactionFactory.build(currency=c)

        valid_serialized_data = {
            'name': transaction.name,
            'currency': transaction.currency.code,
            'email': transaction.email,
            'message': transaction.message,
        }

        serializer = UnfilledTransactionSerializer(data=valid_serialized_data)
        
        assert serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        assert serializer.errors == {}
```

But as soon I remove database acccess from second test case I get this error. I am aware why this error.

```sh
RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

Here is the code of factories

```py
import factory

from apps.Payment.models import Transaction, Currency
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()


class CurrencyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Currency

    # Since currency is declared as a parameter, it won't be passed to 
    # the model (it's automatically added to Meta.exclude.
    class Params:
        currency = factory.Faker("currency")  # (code, name)

    code = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.currency[0])
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.currency[1])
    symbol = '$'


class TransactionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
    
    # if we do not assign these attributes here then they will remain blank
    
    # currency is auto generated on creation of transaction
    currency = factory.SubFactory(CurrencyFactory)
    payment_intent_id = None
    email = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.email())
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.name())
```

## Now the problem

#### I know the Currency instance gets created and saved in database hence the issue. But how to prevent that as I do not want to make database access in unit test and also could not leave serializer without unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer finally. It took me 2 days altough.

**Short Answer**: Do not let Transaction Factory create an dependent instance and save it to DB, create dependency instance seperately and refer to it them. But don't forget to mock the calls where then dependent instance is being called since it do not get saved to DB we need to mock it's call.

**Code**

##### test_serializer.py

```py
from rest_framework.relations import SlugRelatedField

class TestUnfilledTransactionSerializer:
    
    def test_serialized_data(self, mocker):
        # this do not save the instance in DB 
        currency = CurrencyFactory.build()
        transaction = CurrencylessTransactionFactory.build()
        transaction.currency = currency

        valid_serialized_data = {
            'name': transaction.name,
            'currency': transaction.currency.code,
            'email': transaction.email,
            'message': transaction.message,
        }

        # we do this to avoid searching DB for currency instance 
        # with respective currency code
        retrieve_currency = mocker.Mock(return_value=currency)
        SlugRelatedField.to_internal_value = retrieve_currency

        serializer = UnfilledTransactionSerializer(data=valid_serialized_data)
        
        assert serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        assert serializer.errors == {}
```

##### factory.py

```py
import factory

from apps.Payment.models import Transaction, Currency
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

class CurrencylessTransactionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
    
    email = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.email())
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.name())
    message = fake.text()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a unit test by using Python's [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) library. However, I would not recommend it. It seems you are not testing any custom logic here but only testing Django Rest Framework code, which have their own tests.

Comment: **Thanks Dean**, but what if I want to test the output serializer produce, the also in case if it gets break (due to change in model) I think its good to have a unit test. Any other way to do this. (I can move this test to integeration but still looking for any possiblity in unit test).

Comment: I think it would be a lot of work using a unit test here as you would need to overwrite quite a few methods of Django Rest Framework and create a lot of mocked objects which I think would make it unreadable in my opinion. If you need a test, I would use an integration test here.

Comment: If you had some custom validation logic to test on the serializer, it would be simple to unit test using Python's mock library.